# Raw Input - recive WM_INPUT while window/program is in background

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, raw-input

I am trying to monitor and printout the RAWINPUT from a mouse sent to the foreground window, or just all `RAWINPUT` from the mouse in general.

the global hook `LowLevelMouseProc` does not work for me because it returns a `MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT` that does not give me the dx and dy.

The [Raw Input API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-input) mentions that for `WM_INPUT` received when the current window is in the back ground, wParam will be set to `RIM_INPUTSINK`. **But I have no idea how to receive `WM_INPUT` while the program is in the background**.

*here is some code explaining what I am trying to do.*

```cpp
int main()
{
    //regiter the monitoring device
    static bool raw_input_initialized = false;
    if (raw_input_initialized == false)
    {
        RAWINPUTDEVICE rid;

        rid.usUsagePage = 0x01; //Mouse
        rid.usUsage = 0x02;
        rid.dwFlags = 0;
        rid.hwndTarget = NULL;

        if (RegisterRawInputDevices(&rid, 1, sizeof(rid)) == FALSE)
        {
            exit(-1);
        }

        raw_input_initialized = true;
    }

    HWND targetWindow = { 0 };

    while (true)
    {
        targetWindow = GetForegroundWindow(); // get the window runing in the formost window;

        
        std::cout << targetWindow << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}

// enterd every time there is a rawinput to ForegroundWindow, or alternatively just a rawinput in general
LRESULT CALLBACK targetWindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    // print out the values that I need
    case WM_INPUT:
        UINT dataSize;
        GetRawInputData(reinterpret_cast<HRAWINPUT>(lParam), RID_INPUT, NULL, &dataSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)); //Need to populate data size first
        std::cout << GET_RAWINPUT_CODE_WPARAM(wParam) << " code thing\n";
        if (dataSize > 0)
        {

            std::unique_ptr<BYTE[]> rawdata = std::make_unique<BYTE[]>(dataSize);

            if (GetRawInputData(reinterpret_cast<HRAWINPUT>(lParam), RID_INPUT, rawdata.get(), &dataSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)) == dataSize)
            {
                RAWINPUT* raw = reinterpret_cast<RAWINPUT*>(rawdata.get());
                if (raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE)
                {
                    std::cout << raw->data.mouse.lLastX << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Message-Only Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#message-only-windows).

Comment: "*the global hook `LowLevelMouseProc` does not work for me because it returns a `MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT`*" - no, it does not. [Read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/lowlevelmouseproc). It gives you a (pointer to a) `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT` instead. Two different types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I have no idea how to receive WM_INPUT while the program is in the background.

You need to specify the `RIDEV_INPUTSINK` flag when registering the device, per the [`RAWINPUTDEVICE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-rawinputdevice) documentation:

> `dwFlags`
> Type: `DWORD`
>
> Mode flag that specifies how to interpret the information provided by `usUsagePage` and `usUsage`. It can be zero (the default) or one of the following values. By default, the operating system sends raw input from devices with the specified top level collection (TLC) to the registered application **as long as it has the window focus**.
>
> ...
>
> RIDEV_INPUTSINK
> 0x00000100
>
> If set, this enables the caller to receive the input **even when the caller is not in the foreground. Note that `hwndTarget` must be specified**.

As such, you must specify an `HWND` to receive the `WM_INPUT` messages, and have a message loop to service that window.

Try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK targetWindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int main()
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    WNDCLASS wc = {};
    wc.lpfnWndProc = targetWindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("MyRawInputWnd");

    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
        return -1;

    HWND targetWindow = CreateWindowEx(0, wc.lpszClassName, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if (!targetWindow)
        return -1;

    //register the monitoring device
    RAWINPUTDEVICE rid = {};
    rid.usUsagePage = 0x01; //Mouse
    rid.usUsage = 0x02;
    rid.dwFlags = RIDEV_INPUTSINK;
    rid.hwndTarget = targetWindow;

    if (!RegisterRawInputDevices(&rid, 1, sizeof(rid)))
        return -1;

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    DestroyWindow(targetWindow);

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK targetWindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        // print out the values that I need
        case WM_INPUT: {
            UINT dataSize;
            GetRawInputData(reinterpret_cast<HRAWINPUT>(lParam), RID_INPUT, NULL, &dataSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)); //Need to populate data size first
            std::cout << GET_RAWINPUT_CODE_WPARAM(wParam) << " code thing\n";
            if (dataSize > 0)
            {
                std::vector<BYTE> rawdata(dataSize);

                if (GetRawInputData(reinterpret_cast<HRAWINPUT>(lParam), RID_INPUT, rawdata.data(), &dataSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)) == dataSize)
                {
                    RAWINPUT* raw = reinterpret_cast<RAWINPUT*>(rawdata.data());
                    if (raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE)
                    {
                        std::cout << raw->data.mouse.lLastX << std::endl;
                    }
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```